# set latex variable and reuse it

Tags: variables, macros, latex

I want to define a variable for example ``name'', then reuse it in other place in other macros or other part of text.

but following codes do not work correctly.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\name}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\showname}{\name}

\begin{document}

\name{Kiana}

%   My name is ``\showname''

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\name}[1]{\def\showname{#1}}

\begin{document}

\name{Kiana}

   My name is ``\showname''

\end{document}
```

Comment: This code is working well. However, What I write when we want another things such as``\name{Kiana}'' and  ``\surname{Abbassi}''. Then use``\showname'' and get ``Kiana Abbassi''.

Comment: @user9812604 if you have a new question, please ask a new question

Comment: No it is related to this question.

Comment: @user9812604 Good luck then!